# PHPUnit fails on TravisCI, not sure how to debug

Tags: wordpress, phpunit, travis-ci

I'm still trying to teach myself Travis / CI so apologies if the answer is obvious.

I'm trying to determine why my Travis build for a project I've inherited is failing for PHP 7.1 but not 7.2.

Here is the `.travis.yml` config:

```
sudo: false
language: php

# Cache some data across builds for performance.
cache:
  apt: true
  directories:
    - node_modules
    - vendor
    - $HOME/.composer/cache

notifications:
  email:
    on_success: never
    on_failure: change

branches:
  only:
    - master

matrix:
  include:
    - php: 7.2
      env: WP_Version=nightly
    - php: 7.1
      env: WP_VERSION=latest WP_TRAVISCI=phpcs

before_script:
  - export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
  - phpenv config-rm xdebug.ini
  - |
    if [[ ! -z "$WP_VERSION" ]] ; then
      bash bin/install-wp-tests.sh wordpress_test root '' localhost $WP_VERSION
      composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=5.7.*"
    fi
  - |
    if [[ "$WP_TRAVISCI" == "phpcs" ]] ; then
      composer global require wp-coding-standards/wpcs
      phpcs --config-set installed_paths $HOME/.composer/vendor/wp-coding-standards/wpcs
    fi
  - mysql --version
  - phpenv versions
  - php --version

script:
  - |
    if [[ ! -z "$WP_VERSION" ]] ; then
      phpunit --version
      phpunit
      WP_MULTISITE=1 phpunit
    fi
  - |
    if [[ "$WP_TRAVISCI" == "phpcs" ]] ; then
      phpcs --standard=phpcs.ruleset.xml $(find . -name '*.php')
    fi

# If the plugin has any JavaScript or CSS that should be processed,
# add the below to their respective sections so that Grunt is installed
# and all default tasks are run.
#
# To the matrix:
#
#  - php: 7.0
#    env: WP_TRAVISCI=grunt
#
# To before_script:
#
#  - npm --version
#  - node --version
#  - nvm install stable
#  - npm install -g grunt-cli
#  - npm install
#  - npm prune
#  - npm --version
#  - node --version
#
# To script:
#
#  - |
#    if [[ "$WP_TRAVISCI" == "grunt" ]] ; then
#      grunt --version
#      grunt default
#    fi
```

Here is the Travis log:

```
Setting environment variables from .travis.yml
$ export WP_VERSION=latest
$ export WP_TRAVISCI=phpcs
0.02s$ phpenv global 7.1 2>/dev/null
pearrc
Writing /home/travis/.pearrc
0.01s$ phpenv global 7.1
0.87s$ composer self-update
Updating to version 1.9.1 (stable channel).
   Downloading (100%)
Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version 1.8.4
cache.1
Setting up build cache
$ php --version
PHP 7.1.27 (cli) (built: Mar 13 2019 07:54:47) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.27, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.7.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
$ composer --version
Composer version 1.9.1 2019-11-01 17:20:17
before_script.1
0.00s$ export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
before_script.2
0.02s$ phpenv config-rm xdebug.ini
before_script.3
14.36s$ if [[ ! -z "$WP_VERSION" ]] ; then
before_script.4
2.96s$ if [[ "$WP_TRAVISCI" == "phpcs" ]] ; then
before_script.5
0.02s$ mysql --version
before_script.6
0.05s$ phpenv versions
before_script.7
0.06s$ php --version
0.28s$ if [[ ! -z "$WP_VERSION" ]] ; then
  phpunit --version
  phpunit
  WP_MULTISITE=1 phpunit
fi
PHPUnit 5.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /tmp/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1633
wp_die called
Message : <p><code>No such file or directory</code></p>
<h1>Error establishing a database connection</h1>
<p>This either means that the username and password information in your <code>wp-config.php</code> file is incorrect or we can&#8217;t contact the database server at <code>localhost</code>. This could mean your host&#8217;s database server is down.</p>
<ul>
<li>Are you sure you have the correct username and password?</li>
<li>Are you sure you have typed the correct hostname?</li>
<li>Are you sure the database server is running?</li>
</ul>
<p>If you&#8217;re unsure what these terms mean you should probably contact your host. If you still need help you can always visit the <a href="https://wordpress.org/support/forums/">WordPress Support Forums</a>.</p>
Title : 
PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /tmp/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1633
wp_die called
Message : <p><code>No such file or directory</code></p>
<h1>Error establishing a database connection</h1>
<p>This either means that the username and password information in your <code>wp-config.php</code> file is incorrect or we can&#8217;t contact the database server at <code>localhost</code>. This could mean your host&#8217;s database server is down.</p>
<ul>
<li>Are you sure you have the correct username and password?</li>
<li>Are you sure you have typed the correct hostname?</li>
<li>Are you sure the database server is running?</li>
</ul>
<p>If you&#8217;re unsure what these terms mean you should probably contact your host. If you still need help you can always visit the <a href="https://wordpress.org/support/forums/">WordPress Support Forums</a>.</p>
Title : 
The command "if [[ ! -z "$WP_VERSION" ]] ; then
  phpunit --version
  phpunit
  WP_MULTISITE=1 phpunit
fi
" exited with 1.
0.70s$ if [[ "$WP_TRAVISCI" == "phpcs" ]] ; then
  phpcs --standard=phpcs.ruleset.xml $(find . -name '*.php')
fi
The command "if [[ "$WP_TRAVISCI" == "phpcs" ]] ; then
  phpcs --standard=phpcs.ruleset.xml $(find . -name '*.php')
fi
" exited with 0.
cache.2
store build cache
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

I can see the error message is related to the database, but I'm not sure where to look to debug it.

The PHP7.2 job passes.